# ServiceStack.Aws.DynamoDb: Is there async APIs?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, servicestack, pocodynamo

[ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net) is a great library, and I'm now considering using it also for working with [AWS DynamoDb](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/).

However, the only async APIs I can find [are these three](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/IPocoDynamoAsync.cs):

`CreateMissingTablesAsync`
`WaitForTablesToBeReadyAsync`
`InitSchemaAsync`

Is there any reason not to create async APIs for the rest? Are async APIs in the pipeline, or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason Async overloads shouldn't exist, it's currently not in any pipeline since the [feature has never been requested](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).

All feature requests for any ServiceStack Software should be requested on https://servicestack.uservoice.com where demand for the feature can be recorded, prioritized and voters are able to get notified when the feature gets implemented..

Comment: Alright, request created: https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/38400211-pocodynamo-async-apis